# Return custom response if Django permission denied

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i tried to implement a permission in Django via a decorator class.
There I check if the user is Authenticated and in addition what role the user has(ADMIN, HQ_ADMIN, ...)

Here is my code:

```
class UserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            return False

        method = request.method
        authenticator = request._authenticator

        response = self.check_permission_roles(request)

        if(response == None):
            if method == 'POST' and isinstance(authenticator, BasicAuthentication):
                return True

            if method == 'PUT' and isinstance(authenticator, BasicAuthentication):
                return True

            if method == 'DELETE' and isinstance(authenticator, BasicAuthentication):
                return True

            if method == 'GET':
                return True

        return False


    def check_permission_roles(self, request):
        """ checks the roles from the logged-in user """

        headers =  {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}

        logged_in_user_roles = request.user.roles
        new_roles = request.DATA[models.ROLES]

        # check roles for create ADMIN
        if models.ADMIN in new_roles:
            if models.ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                return Response("no right to create role: ADMIN", status=400, headers=headers)

        # check roles for create HQ_ADMIN
        if models.HQ_ADMIN in new_roles:
            if models.ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                if models.HQ_ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                    return Response("no right to create role: HQ_ADMIN", status=400, headers=headers)

        # check roles for create HQ_USER
        if models.HQ_USER in new_roles:
            if models.ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                if models.HQ_ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                    return Response("no right to create role: HQ_USER", status=400, headers=headers)

        # check roles for create WORKSHOP_USER
        if models.WORKSHOP_USER in new_roles:
            if models.ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                if models.HQ_ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                    if models.HQ_USER not in logged_in_user_roles:
                        return Response("no right to create role: WORKSHOP_USER", status=400, headers=headers)

        # check roles for create DRIVER
        if models.DRIVER in new_roles:
            if models.ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                if models.HQ_ADMIN not in logged_in_user_roles:
                    if models.HQ_USER not in logged_in_user_roles:
                        if models.WORKSHOP_USER not in logged_in_user_roles:
                            return Response("no right to create role: DRIVER", status=400, headers=headers)

        return None
```

If i send a post command now, and the check_permission_roles method returns not None, I want Django to send the Response returned from the check_permission_roles function instead of the standard response(403, You do not have permission to perform this action.).

How can I prevent Django from returning the default response and instead return the custom response?

Answer (score 0):

**answering an old question**

You can create a custom exception handler, and within that you can handle the 'PermissionDenied' exception with desired error code and message

```
def core_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    handlers = {
        'PermissionDenied': _handle_error,
    }
    exception_class = exc.__class__.__name__

    if exception_class in handlers:
        return handlers[exception_class](exc, context, response)

    return response

def _handle_error(exc, context, response):
    response.status_code=401 #setting response code as 401
    response.data = {
        'errors': response.data
   }

   return response
```

something like this.